# SQL server compare a field with another that is composed of a list separated by commas of the 1st field

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute the below query but I have a problem.

I cannot use 
`tTerritorio.terrNome = tContactoTerritorio.territorios` because `territorios` is a list of several terrNome separated by `,`

How can I make this match so that I can retrieve the information I need?

```
select terrNome As Territorio, espDescricao AS Especialidade, COUNT (distinct contNome) AS 'Nº Médicos'
from tContacto, tContactoTerritorio, tTerritorio,tEspecialidade
where tContacto.contID=tContactoTerritorio.contID and tContacto.tpcontID=120
and tTerritorio.terrNome = tContactoTerritorio.territorios
and (tEspecialidade.espID=tContacto.esp1ID or tEspecialidade.espID=tContacto.esp2ID or
tEspecialidade.espID=tContacto.esp3ID or tEspecialidade.espID=tContacto.esp4ID or 
tEspecialidade.espID=tContacto.esp5ID)
group by terrnome, espdescricao
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple like will work for you:

```
','+tContactoTerritorio.territorios+',' like '%,'+tTerritorio.terrNome+',%'
```

I'm adding commas at the beginning and end of `territorios` assuming the first and last occurrences don't have them. Then you look for `'%,terrnome,%'`.
(Obviously this is a terrible way to search for a string but it's also a terrible way to store data)

```
SELECT terrNome             AS Territorio,
  espDescricao              AS Especialidade,
  COUNT (DISTINCT contNome) AS 'Nº Médicos'
FROM tContacto,
  tContactoTerritorio,
  tTerritorio,
  tEspecialidade
WHERE tContacto.contID   =tContactoTerritorio.contID
AND tContacto.tpcontID   =120
AND ','+tContactoTerritorio.territorios+',' like '%,'+tTerritorio.terrNome+',%'
AND (tEspecialidade.espID=tContacto.esp1ID
OR tEspecialidade.espID  =tContacto.esp2ID
OR tEspecialidade.espID  =tContacto.esp3ID
OR tEspecialidade.espID  =tContacto.esp4ID
OR tEspecialidade.espID  =tContacto.esp5ID)
GROUP BY terrnome,
  espdescricao
```

Comment: Maybe, add some conditions (via OR) for cases when target name is in beginning or in the end. +1 to terrible database design

Comment: As for the terrible DB design it's kind of our fault for asking the developers to associate territories with contacts after they already finished the app. I do agree though that it was a poor implementation

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server 2016, use the [STRING_SPLIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx) function.

If using a version prior to 2016, this great article has all the information you need http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html